# IE browse image from blobestorage in new tab not working, but in Chrome works as well

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, blobstore

1. I am using Angular 4 on UI.
2. Image dowloaded by url. As i understand
   it is convertet to blob storage and we have such 
   link(blob:9C3A4E2E-488F-4C64-A1CD-7E4C4E464187) when browser
   elements at browser.
3. I want to be able to open this image from storage instead of request it 
   again at new tab.It's works in Chome, but not working in UI

   ```
       private onImageClick($event) {
          var url = $event.srcElement.src;
          window.open(url, '_blank');
       }

   <a href="" target="_blank" (click)="onImageClick($event)">
   <img class="height-75 img-thumbnail" http-src="{{model.someUrl}}" />
   </a>
   ```